# Why does a CUDA Reduction algorithm skip over whole sections of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

I am trying to use one of the Reduction Kernels talked about in the official CUDA Reduction PDF [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf). However, I am not understanding how it really works, unless I am missing something it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Here's my Kernel:

```
__global__ void energyKernel(int nbodies, int *addReduc, int *subReduc, int *inData, int *inData2){
    extern __shared__ int e[];

    unsigned int tID = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = tID + blockIdx.x * (blockDim.x * 2);

    if (tID < nbodies && (i + blockDim.x) < nbodies){
        e[tID] = inData[i] + inData[i + blockDim.x];
    }
    else{
        e[tID] = inData[i];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    for (unsigned int stride = blockDim.x / 2; stride > 32; stride >>= 1)
    {
        if (tID < stride)
        {
            e[tID] += e[tID + stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();


    }

    if (tID < 32){ warpReduce(e, tID); }

    if (tID == 0)
    {
        addReduc[blockIdx.x] = e[0];
    } 
}
```

I was trying to figure out how the loading of data from the inData array to shared memory worked so I carried out a few calculations. The code was originally loading data as follows:

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
e[tid] = inData[i];
__syncthreads();
```

So if inData was an array of 3000 ints, and I launched the Kernel with 3 Blocks each with 1024 threads then each thread would access the inData array with its thread "address" i.e Thread 512 of Block 1 would be

> 1 * 1024 + 512 = 1536

So it would access the 1536th element of inData.

However with the new code:

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;
sdata[tid] = g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockDim.x];
__syncthreads();
```

Thread 0 of Block 0 would of course access

> 0 * 0*2 + 0 = 0

But Thread 0 of Block 1 would access

> 1 * 1024*2 + 0 = 2048

So the inData values from 1024 - 2047 are completely ignored.

Am I missing something very obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
sdata[tid] = g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockDim.x];
```

Hence for thread 0 block 0 you have that `g_idata[i+blockDim.x]` is `g_idata[0 + 1024]` , hence it is not skipped, right?

Comment: Wow. Of course. Well that was a stupid question. Thank you!

Comment: Such details are often overlooked :)